# Determining destination window in keystroke event handler

Tags: macos, event-handling, keyboard

Several approaches to keystroke notification have been suggested.  In 10.6, there's the idea of the global event monitor, by means of addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatachingMask.  In earlier releases, there's the Carbon Event Manager, and GetEventMonitorTarget.  And there's the CoreGraphics event tap, as in CGEventTapCreate.

These ideas all came from NSGod in the response to the question [here](http://ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752427/osx-detect-system-wide-keydown-events-solved-with-sample-code).

In any or all of these techniques, is it possible to determine, at the point of the event handler, which window is the destination for the keystroke?